# Garbled text, copied lines in vim over ssh

Tags: vim, ssh

I've had this issue often where if I compile vim myself on a server (due to lack of root permissions), at various times, I'll get garbled lines in vim when I have split windows. This is hard to describe, and thus hard to search for, as well.

Here's an image of a vim window. In each split is my .vimrc. Everything is good right now:

[image: vim split where life is good]

Now, I hit some  in the right split to scroll down, and suddenly, we have garbled text and line 176 showing up everywhere:

[image: vim split where life is not good]

This is not particular to any specific file. I've tried removing all my plugins, and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the offending line was

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

in my .vimrc. I basically commented out my entire vimrc, and searched through until I realized this line was the issue, and I'm not entirely sure why.